# jQuery Validate - Add generic message for rule

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Previously I had static fields where I could use the following:

```
rules {
    input_field: {
        required: true,
        digits: true
     },
     messages: {
         input_field: "Input_field is invalid"
     }
}
```

This would display that message for any of the rules set on that input.

Now I need to use dynamic inputs (input_field1, input_field2, etc) and am using the following which works fine:

```
$("#input_field"+i).rules("add", {required: true, digits: true})
```

The problem I'm facing is when adding a message it seems I'm required to set the message for a specific failure like so:

```
$("#input_field"+i).rules("add", {required: true, digits: true, messages: {required: "Input_field required"}})
```

Is there a way I can set a generic message for the input's failure as I did with the static rules instead of having to set a different message for each failure reason?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get around by using the `title` attribute instead of setting messages. jQuery Validate uses it by default.

```
<input type="text" title="Input Field ' + i + ' is invalid" name="input_field' + i + '"/>
```

and

```
$("#input_field"+i).rules("add", {required: true, digits: true})
```